# How to reverse an array if we have a property?

Tags: javascript

I have an array `dataAllDate` this might has or has not `dataAllDate.positiveIncrease` and if it does, then we need to reverse the `dataAllDate` order.

Tried this

```
if(dataAllDate['positiveIncrease']) {
   console.lgo("hello");
   dataAllDate.reverse();
}
```

Basically I am receiving this:

```
var dataAllDate = JSON.parse("["+dataAllDateToJason+"]");
```

But `dataAllDate` are not identical all the times, so I need to check that key and if it does, I need to reverse the array.

**UPDATE**

This is the data:

```
allDates: Array(65)
0: {date: "2/24/20", ricoverati_con_sintomi: 0, terapia_intensiva: 0, totale_ospedalizzati: 0, isolamento_domiciliare: 0, …}
1: {date: "2/25/20", ricoverati_con_sintomi: 0, terapia_intensiva: 0, totale_ospedalizzati: 0, isolamento_domiciliare: 0, …}
```

Comment: how your `dataAllDate` looks like ?

Comment: You mean you have an array of Objects `dataAllDate`?

Comment: I fail to understand how `var dataAllDate = JSON.parse("["+dataAllDateToJason+"]");` can ever add the `positiveIncrease` property to the array.

Comment: if it's an array and you haven't added a index named `positiveIncrease` you're accessing array wrongly, you need to access the index

Comment: @CodeManiac updated the question with the data

Comment: if it's an array and you haven't added a index named `positiveIncrease` you're accessing array wrongly, you need to access the index

Comment: @VLAZ on production I am doing `dataAllDate.forEach(nationData => {
            nationData.allDates.forEach(day => { ` but I need to reverse it before that

Comment: So if any of the 65 contain `positiveIncrease`, you would want to reverse the whole array?

Comment: @UtsavPatel exactly, that's what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
if(hasPositiveIncrease(dataAllDate)){
  dataAllDate.reverse()
}
```

You can define `hasPositiveIncrease` like so:

```
const hasPositiveIncrease = (dataAllDate) => 
  dataAllDate.find((item) => item.hasPositiveIncrease);
```

This will return the first element that has positiveIncrease.

Working snippet attached.

```js
const dataAllDate = [
  {
    date: "2/24/20",
    ricoverati_con_sintomi: 0,
    terapia_intensiva: 0,
    totale_ospedalizzati: 0,
    isolamento_domiciliare: 0,
  },
  {
    date: "2/25/20",
    ricoverati_con_sintomi: 0,
    terapia_intensiva: 0,
    totale_ospedalizzati: 0,
    isolamento_domiciliare: 0,
  },
  {
    date: "2/26/20",
    ricoverati_con_sintomi: 0,
    terapia_intensiva: 0,
    totale_ospedalizzati: 0,
    isolamento_domiciliare: 0,
  },
  {
    date: "2/27/20",
    ricoverati_con_sintomi: 0,
    terapia_intensiva: 0,
    totale_ospedalizzati: 0,
    isolamento_domiciliare: 0,
    hasPositiveIncrease: 1
  },
];

const hasPositiveIncrease = (dataAllDate) => 
  dataAllDate.find((item) => item.hasPositiveIncrease);
  
 if(hasPositiveIncrease(dataAllDate)){
  console.log(dataAllDate.reverse())
 }
```

Comment: No need for `.find` - if you just want a boolean, then use `.some`

Comment: The problem with `.some` is that it checks for at least one element.
This means it traverses the whole array.

Whereas `.find` will return the first element it finds that satisfies the condition.

Although, I can't say about the performance difference between the two, but I use find much more than some.

Comment: The two...work identically. "At least one element" means it returns after the first time it matches. Why would it continue traversing the entire array after finding a match? The only difference is that `.some` returns a boolean, while `.find` returns the element.

Comment: Actually `.some()` works the same as `.find()` it return true immediately if it finds a matching value.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Array.some()`

```js
const dataAllDate = [{
    date: "2/24/20",
    ricoverati_con_sintomi: 0,
    terapia_intensiva: 0,
    totale_ospedalizzati: 0,
    isolamento_domiciliare: 0,
    positiveIncrease: true,
},
{ 
    date: "2/25/20",
    ricoverati_con_sintomi: 0,
    terapia_intensiva: 0,
    totale_ospedalizzati: 0,
    isolamento_domiciliare: 0 
}];

const positiveIncreaseExists = dataAllDate.some(item => item.positiveIncrease);
if (positiveIncreaseExists) {
    dataAllDate.reverse();
}

console.log(dataAllDate);
```

Comment: thanks! let's use the correct naming for future users tho, dataAllDate